# Can someone provide complete working Rest API Sample request to add & delete objects in amazon s3 bucket?

Tags: file, rest, amazon-s3, directory, http-delete

I want to delete files and folder from the Amazon s3 bucket. Below is my request, but its not working.

```
     $.ajax({ 
         type: "POST",
         dataType: "jsonp",

         url: "http://s3.amazonaws.com/bucketname/",
          beforeSend: function( xhr ) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Action','DELETE');
            xhr.setRequestHeader('AWSAccessKeyId','AWSAccessKeyId');
            xhr.setRequestHeader('signature','signature');
            xhr.overrideMimeType( "application/octet-stream" );
         },
          success: function(data){  alert("IN SUCCESS"); alert(data);  },
          error: function(data) {  alert(data);}

     });
```

Comment: Not sure if your use case is what I think it is, but is your signature really set to the string 'signature'.  Perhaps have a look at this page: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RESTAPI.html, and this page: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/S3_Authentication2.html

Comment: Did you ever get this working?